# How to find individual breaking change in a large commit

Tags: git

I made some source changes to lint my code. I did not run unit tests, and later I found that a large commit broke the code. **How do I go back and find out which code change in a number of files broke the tests?**

I could:

1. diff the working (earlier) commit against the breaking (later) commit
2. save the result in a patch file
3. patch/test cycle

   1. apply parts of the patch file to the earlier commit
   2. run the tests

I am hoping git has something less manual than this.

Comment: Your commits should be atomic. Git can't help you if you make massive bloated commits, it's not magic.

Comment: @meager: Setting aside the difficulty of defining an atomic change to source code... I think the OP knows now that he should try to make small commits, and should run the tests. But Git *can* help here, because it's an SCM not just a VCS, and that's what the OP's asking about.

Comment: Re: "Your commits should be atomic." In this case, the problem occurs in a commit that merged one branch into another. I don't know an easy way to avoid that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a decent way to do this using the ability of `git-stash` to not only stash away and reapply changes, but also the state of the index. It goes something like this:

```
# check out the bad commit
git checkout bad-commit
# and then reset to the commit before, leaving the bad changes in the work tree
git reset HEAD^

# stage the things you want to keep/test first
git add -p
# stash away the rest (keep the staged parts)
git stash --keep-index
# now build/test. if it works, go ahead and commit it
git commit
# bring back the stashed changes
git stash pop
# repeat!
git add -p
git stash --keep-index
# now suppose the broken part is in what you kept, and you want to split it up more
# unstage the changes
git reset
# and then repeat!
git add -p
git stash --keep-index
# if you do this, you'll end up with multiple stashes; you can check on them:
git stash list
git stash show
git stash show -p stash@{1}
```

Using stashes and testing as you go along has the advantage that if you manage to pick a subset of the changes which simply breaks the build, you can just pop the stash back off, and try again.

You could do something similar to split up the commit into many, then run `git bisect` on it, but often that's more work, since it's more difficult to know how to split things up without testing as you go along.

Of course, now you know that you should make smaller commits. But I don't always do it right the first time either!

Comment: I ended up doing essentially this. See below.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your commit to several small ones, and then use `git bisect` to find the offending commit. The easiest way to that is to use **interactive rebase**:

1. If you already pushed you commit, then create a new branch with `git checkout -b <name>`, otherwise you're good to go.
2. Run `git rebase -i <bad commit>^`
3. An editor will pop up with one or more lines, each indicating a commit. On the line of the offending commit, change the first word from `pick` to `edit`, then save and close the editor.
4. Git will now stop in the middle of the rebase, when all the changes of your offending commit are staged. Now we separate this large commit into smaller ones by doing a `git reset` on the changed files, and then committing each change on its own.
5. When you're done, do `git rebase --continue` to complete the rebase procedure.

You've now split your commit into several smaller ones, and you can more easily find out exactly which change is broken. A very efficient way of doing that is using `git bisect`. What that does is perform a **binary search** of commits in order to find exactly the one that is broken, which is precisely what you want to achieve. This is how you use it:

1. Run `git bisect start`.
2. Run `git bisect good <good commit>`, where `<good commit>` is a hash/tag/whatever of a commit you know worked. You can use the commit before the first of the split commits you just made.
3. Run `git bisect bad <bad commit>`, where `<bad commit>` is a has/tag/whatever of a commit you know *doesn't* work. You can use `HEAD` for this since you know it's broken.
4. Git will now checkout some commit in that range and ask you to test it. Perform your test, then tell git whether it's good or bad by running `git bisect good` or `git bisect bad`, respectively. Git will continue to checkout other commits, according to what you tell it.
5. After some steps, git will tell you exactly which commit is the one broken. You can then use `git show <commit>` to see what it contains.
6. Run `git bisect reset` to quit bisect mode.

To learn more about these subject, continue reading on:

1. Git Book about [git bisect](http://book.git-scm.com/5_finding_issues_-_git_bisect.html) and [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html).
2. Pro Git book about [git bisect](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html) and [interactive rebase](http://progit.org/book/ch6-5.html).
3. The git man pages (which are excellent, by the way!), with `git rebase --help` and `git bisect --help`.

Comment: This is a reasonable thing to do, but not necessarily the most efficient. You don't always know how you want to split everything right off the bat, and without testing every newly-split commit, you're likely to introduce new breakages too. It's probably better to test as you go, unless your tests are really large. Bisect is much better suited to a commit history that's already appropriately split, or maybe a project whose tests are all very time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing essentially what Jefromi suggested. I wrote this python code, naming it git-bisect.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from sys import stderr


def run_command(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode:
        raise Exception(errors)


def process_all(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        all_files = [fn.strip() for fn in f]
    try:
        for i, f in enumerate(all_files, start=1):
            print >> stderr, i, f
            run_command(['git', 'add', f])
            run_command(['git', 'stash', '--keep-index'])
            run_command(['bin/login_test.sh'])
            run_command(['git', 'stash', 'pop'])
    except Exception, exc:
        print >> stderr, exc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    for filename in argv[1:]:
        process_all(filename)
```

And ran it against a list of files that had been affected.

Here was my complete workflow:

```
# Get the commit just before things went bad
git checkout 8f5c3d7
# Diff good code against bad, make patch
git diff 8f5c3d7 cb8ddf0 > 8f5c3d7-cb8ddf0.patch
# Apply patch
git apply 8f5c3d7-cb8ddf0.patch

# Now my index has all the changes that went into the bad commit
# but with just a dirty index.

# Run code that finds bad file in commit
python ~/Dropbox/src/git-bisect.py ~/Dropbox/src/bad-commit.txt
```

And this chugged along until it stopped on the first bad file. Then I would just:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and reapply the patch, put the bad file at the end of the file list and start over. Soon I knew ever file that had changes that broke my build.